# Encoding Json Correctly?

Tags: php, json

Alright, So I'm redoing my question so people can understand what I'm trying to do.

Search.php

```
<?php
$getItems = file_get_contents('Items.json');
if(isset($_GET['searchVal'])){
    $getItems2 = json_decode($getItems, true);
    $data2 = array("items" => array(array()));
    foreach($getItems2['items'] as $data){
        if(strpos($data['name'], $_GET['searchVal'])){
             $data2 = array("items" => array(array($data)));
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data2,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
} else{
    echo $getItems;
}
```

Problem: Doesn't get all items which have that name, gets only one.

Search is done, now I have to fix somehow to get all items which match the name. How could I do that?

Comment: Can you post your array

Comment: What's actually going wrong? P.s. your `echo json_encode` line should probably be outside the foreach loop, otherwise you'll end up with invalid JSON being output when there are multiple items.

Comment: Do you want `data` as a key?

Comment: Yeah, but if I move it out from the loop then it doesn't show it correctly anymore. If I search for Karambit, then it only shows one weapon which is M4

Comment: Because you should probably be using `$data[] = array(...` and defining the array before the loop. But then we don't know what you're after so who knows.

Comment: I could re-explain what I'm trying to do if it was unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following inside a loop:

```
$data2 = array(...)
```

...and then you reference `$data2` outside the loop.

Of course, it will only contain the last entry, because that line is overwriting `$data2` with new data each time the loop iterates.

If you want to keep all the records from the loop, use

```
$data2[] = array(...)
```

instead.

[EDIT]

Further guessing as to what you actually want your JSON to look like, I guess you want all the records to be in the `items` array?

So in that case, let's rewrite your `$data2` line, as follows:

```
$data2['items'][] = array($data);
```

This will add all the data arrays to your `items` array in `$data2`. I will note that your array structure is really convoluted -- too many nested arrays, which makes it difficult to be sure I'm giving you the answer you want even now, but hopefully if it isn't exactly right, it will show you the direction you need to go.

You'll also want to have an additional line at the top of your code to initialise `$data2`, like this:

```
$data2 = array('items'=>array());
```

This should be somewhere at the top of the code, before `$data2` is used, and outside of the loop.

Comment: Yeah, using that would be perfect, but that messes up JSON output :/ is there any other ways?

Comment: uh, well it depends what your JSON output is supposed to be. You haven't really specified. But I'll try to make a guess and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It is almost perfect, only one thing what messes up the JSON is `[]` in JSON

Comment: so drop the extra array() layer around $data. (I kept it as it was in your original structure, but I'd say it's probably not necessary)

Comment: Just idk gonna put these are: http://prntscr.com/bhjp8w - Like this perfect, just not all there. And if I use that `$data2['items'][] = array($data)` then http://prntscr.com/bhjphm those I want to get rid of somehow

Comment: So like I said in previous comment, get rid of the extra array() layer. `$data2['items'][] = $data;`

Comment: Alright, seems like everything works perfectly except that I still have `[]` in JSON which ends up to be actually a problem. Because of  that it creates empty box thinking there's no information in it.